# are there public ideas/concepts for space mining machines?

Tags: asteroid, mining

If a company were to send a rocket into space they would need some kind of mining machine on board to mine on, for example, an asteroid. I was wondering if a company already has a good idea for a mining machine and has public details on its weight and price. I need to know this for a project I'm doing on asteroid mining. I hope this question isn't too vague and someone could help me with it. I haven't been able to find anything, only drawings and concept but nothing about size, weight and price.

Comment: Have you tried searching? It will be better if you mention some research you've done by yourself within the question, so people know what you've done so far and don't end up duplicating what you have already.

Comment: Suspect there are no really useful numbers, since there are so many unknowns in space processing of ores and the actual mining depends a great deal on how it is to be processed, and that in part depends on what type and quality the market wants to buy. And at the moment there is no market. Similarly without space mining it is very expensive to get the material to make a space mining machine...